# Do Upcasting effects on Static methods?

Tags: java, upcasting

Why It calls base class method when we declare method as static in base as well as in derive class and do upcasting.

```
class Base
{
    static void show(){
        System.out.println("Base class....");
    }
}
class Derive extends Base
{
    static void show(){
        System.out.println("Drive class....");
    }//method hidding.....

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Base b= new Derive();
            b.show();           
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't override static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Base.show`, not `Derive.show`. Method hiding is not overriding.

[§8.4.8.2. of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) gives an example that demonstrates exactly what happens here:

> A class (`static`) method that is hidden can be invoked by using a reference whose type is the class that actually contains the declaration of the method. In this respect, hiding of `static` methods is different from overriding of instance methods. The example:
>
> ```
> class Super {
>     static String greeting() { return "Goodnight"; }
>     String name() { return "Richard"; }
> }
> class Sub extends Super {
>     static String greeting() { return "Hello"; }
>     String name() { return "Dick"; }
> }
> class Test {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Super s = new Sub();
>         System.out.println(s.greeting() + ", " + s.name());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> produces the output:
>
> `Goodnight, Dick`
>
> because the invocation of greeting uses the type of `s`, namely `Super`, to figure out, at compile time, which class method to invoke, whereas the invocation of `name` uses the class of `s`, namely `Sub`, to figure out, at run-time, which instance method to invoke.

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues here to mention:

- static methods are not inherited and not overridden by the sub-classes
- static methods do not need an instance to be called, they need a class

So, basically, calling `b.show();` actually means calling `Base.show();`

Answer (score 1):

Just one more completion to the answers above. It's best to invoke class methods by their class not by an instance variable: `Base.show()`  not `b.show()` to make clear that the method is a static method. This is especially useful in your case when you are hiding a method, not overriding it.